# How to hide the Post Controller name & method from URL using Codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am using Codeigniter 3 and trying to hide the Controller file name and method from the URL but it's not working. In the below example "CommonPages" is the Controller file name and "postdetails" is the method.

```
www.mydomain.com/CommonPages/postDetails/social-testing-post
www.mydomain.com/CommonPages/postDetails/fix-the-windows-errors
```

I want to hide `CommonPages/postDetails` from the URL. There are around 100 of posts so it would be great if I do not specify each and every page link in the `route.php` file. Alternatively, I have tried the below code in `route.php` but it didn't worked for me.

```
$route['(:any)'] = 'CommonPages/postDetails/$1';
$route['(:num)'] = 'CommonPages/postDetails/$1';
$route['([a-zA-Z0-9]+)'] = "CommonPages/postDetails/$1";
```

Thanks all.

Comment: Your routes can be anything at all.  So what do you *want* the URL to be?  Let's say you want `posts/something`, then you would add a route like: `$route['posts/(:any)'] = 'CommonPages/postDetails/$1';`

Comment: I really suggest you take a few minutes and skim the docs, your development will be so much smoother if you have a handle on these basics.  [The tutorial](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/tutorial/index.html) gives a quick overview of most key details, including routing.  And [the URLs section](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/urls.html) gives more detail about routing when you need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$route['product/:num'] = 'catalog/product_lookup';
```

In a route, the array key contains the **URI** to be matched, while the array value contains the destination it should be re-routed to.

In the above example, if the literal word `product` is found in the first segment of the **URL**, and a number is found in the second segment, the `catalog` class and the `product_lookup` method are instead used.

You need config better the routes check this for more info:

https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html

Comment: Maybe you want something like that.

$route['social-testing-post/(:any)'] = 'CommonPages/postDetails/$1';

Comment: Hi @Ak1to I have added like this
$route['default_controller'] = 'home';
$route['social-testing-post/(:any)'] = 'CommonPages/postDetails/$1';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;

But still I can see the Class and method in the URL:
mydomain.com/CommonPages/postDetails/social-testing-post

Comment: @Jennifer unless you use that URL on your site, nobody can see it. `CommonPages/postDetails/social-testing-post` will always work, because Codeigniter maps URLs to controllers/methods. But if you set up a route, you can use a *different* URL to get to that page, and the Controller/method version will never be visible or public, it will never be used.

Comment: Hi @Hasan @VictorLee and @Ak1to. Finally `$route['(:any)'] = 'CommonPages/postDetails/$1';` worked for me by placing under `routes.php` and secondly removed `CommonPages/postDetails` from anchor tags e.g: `<a href="CommonPages/postDetails/<?php echo $top['slug']; ?>">` I really appreciate your help. Thanks

Comment: You can also use the helper URL Helper

Answer (score 0):

you can directly update your routes

```
$route['CommonPages/postDetails/(:any)'] = 'anyClass/anyMethod';
```

on anyMethod you can get the uri segment for getting param

```
public function anyMethod ()
        {
        print_r($this->uri->segments);
        }
```

Comment: Hi @Hasan. Thanks for your reply. I have tried but it's not working for me. Could you please have a look at the controller file screenshot.  I have updated the question.

Comment: OP said "*I want to hide CommonPages/postDetails from the URL*" - how does adding a route for `CommonPages/postDetails/` help?

Comment: Hi Hasan. Yes I need to hide `CommonPages/postDetails/` but above method is not working